# Show that $U\cap V\neq\{0\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is the question I am trying to solve:

Suppose that $U$ and $V$ are $4$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^6$ and that $\dim(U+V)=6$. Show that $U\cap V\neq\{0\}$.

I don't know how to approach this question. I've heard that it's supposed to be "easy", which is discouraging to say the least.

My only guess is that it has something to do with the basis, but I could be completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go about this (in a less linear algebra way): think Pigeonhole principle.

That is, if $dim$ $U=4$ and $dim$ $V=4$, and they are both subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^6$, then how many dimensions *must* they intersect in?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use hte following relation

$$ \dim( U + V) + \dim( U \cap V ) = \dim U + \dim V $$

solution: (for your pleasure)

If $U \cap V = \{ 0 \} $, then $\dim ( U \cap V) = 0 $. It follows that $6 = 8 $, which is false.

Answer (score 0):

Let be $\{u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4\}$ a basis for $U$, and $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ a basis for $V$. Supponse $U\cap V=\{0\}$, We will show that $\{u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is linear independt and then we get a contradiction since there is not subspace of $R^6$ with dimension 8. Let be $t_1,...,t_8\in R$ such that $t_1 u_1+...+t_4u_4+t_5v_1+...+t_8v_4=0$
then, $$w=t_1 u_1+...+t_4u_4=-t_5v_1-...-t_8v_4$$

Since $w$ is linear combination of $u_i$, then $w\in U$, and since $w$ is linear combination of $v_i$ then $w\in V$ so $w\in U\cap V$, the for the hypothesis $w=0$. So must be $t_1=t_2=...=t_8=0$, since  $\{u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4\}$ and  $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ are basis, so we get a contradition, then  $U\cap V\not =\{0\}$

Answer (score 0):

It is a general fact that if $U\cap V=\{0\}$ then the union of any basis of $U$ with any basis of $V$ is a linearly *independent* set. This is because, calling $u_i$ the basis vectors for $U$ and $v_j$ the basis vectors of $v$, a linear relation $\sum_ic_iu_i+\sum_jd_jv_j=0$ can be rewritten as $\sum_ic_iu_i=-\sum_jd_jv_j$, where now the left hand side is in $U$ and the right hand side in $V$, so both sides are in $U\cap V$, hence equal to $0$ by the hypothesis. Since individually the $\{u_1,\ldots\}$ and $\{v_1,\ldots\}$ are linearly independent, this forces all coefficients $c_j$ and $d_j$ to be zero, proving that all the basis vectors together are linearly independent.

But this means that $U\cap V=\{0\}$ implies $\dim(U+V)=\dim(U)+\dim(V)$, since the union of any basis of $U$ with any basis of $V$ clearly *spans* $U+V$, so by linear independence is a basis of $U+V$. But in the example $\dim(U+V)=6\neq\dim(U)+\dim(V)=4+4=8$.

In case $U\cap V=\{0\}$, the sum $U+V$ is called a *direct sum*, and the additivity of dimensions for direct sums is a very useful property. (Sums of more than two subspaces are defined to be direct precisely when the dimensions add up; this can however no longer be ascertained by looking just at intersections of the subspaces.)